# How to map sql DATE to LocalDate

Tags: java, jdbc, timezone, java-8, sqldatetime

I want to store a `LocalDate` in a `DATE` column and retrieve it unchanged. Both `DATE` and `LocalDate` are "local" types by definition. Therefore, the concept of *timezone* should not interfere in any way.

The code below is a minimal example that creates a table with a `DATE` column in a in-memory database. The maven artifact `com.h2database:h2:1.4.192` must be in the classpath.

First, define methods `insert` and `retrieve`:

```
static void insert(DataSource ds, String date) throws SQLException {
  try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
       Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE people (id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT"
      + ", born DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) );");
    stmt.execute("INSERT INTO people (born) VALUES ('" + date + "')");
  }
}

static LocalDate retrieve(DataSource ds) throws SQLException {
  try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
       Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM people limit 1")) {
    if (rs.next()) {
      java.sql.Date retrieved = java.sql.Date.valueOf(rs.getString("born"));
      return retrieved.toLocalDate();
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("No data");
  }
}
```

Notice that the `insert` method uses the `toString` value of the `LocalDate` in single quotes, so there's no opportunity for Java™ to create timezone ambiguity. Now call `insert` once and then several times `retrieve`, with different timzone settings each time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  DataSource ds = JdbcConnectionPool.create("jdbc:h2:mem:test", "sa", "sa");
  LocalDate born = LocalDate.parse("2015-05-20");
  insert(ds, born.toString());
  System.out.println("Inserted:  " + born);
  for (int i : new int[]{-14, 0, 12}) {
    TimeZone z = TimeZone.getTimeZone(String.format("Etc/GMT%+02d", i));
    TimeZone.setDefault(z);
    System.out.println("Retrieved: " + retrieve(ds));
  }
}
```

Then the following is printed:

```
Inserted:  2015-05-20
Retrieved: 2015-05-20
Retrieved: 2015-05-19
Retrieved: 2015-05-18
```

How to write the `retrieve` method so that it returns the same value that was inserted *unconditionally*, assuming that the database table doesn't change?

Comment: Are you importing java.util.Date?  On that `retrieved =` line you use the fully-qualified `java.sql.Date` on the left side of assignment but not the right.

Comment: Why were you expecting the 3 same `LocalDate` to be printed? You're inserting the date `2015-05-20`. Then, when you change the default time-zone, the `java.sql.Date.toLocalDate` method will return different result.

Comment: @BasilBourque fixed

Comment: @Tunaki I'm not expecting this code to work, I know it doesn't. I'm asking how to write it, so that it does. Both LocalDate and DATE are suitable for birthdays, i.e. Timezone-agnostic. System timezone should not be taken into consideration, this only happens because java forces the conversion to `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: To not be tied implicitely to the system timezone, I expect (or would like) to be in the wrong here, but I'd just use a `String` with `return LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("born"));`...

Comment: @Tunaki Correct, `rs.getString("born")` can still be used, even if `born` is a `DATE` and not `varchar`. Please make a full anwer, so that I can accept.

Comment: @LarsBohl I think it only works because H2 stores DATE [as yyyy-MM-dd](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#date_type), not really something that I'd recommend. However, I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548331/missed-opportunity-to-fix-jdbc-date-handling-in-java-8 and the code in the question appears to solve this issue (i.e. if you use the provided `getLocalDate`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114503/discussion-between-lars-bohl-and-tunaki).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried the following modification to your `retrieve` method and it worked for me:

The [H2 documentation for the DATE Type](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#date_type) says that it is

> The date data type. The format is yyyy-MM-dd.

So, instead of your ...

```java
java.sql.Date retrieved = (java.sql.Date) rs.getObject("born");
return retrieved.toLocalDate();
```

... I just used ...

```java
return LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("born"));
```

... and my code produced

```
Inserted:  2015-05-20
Retrieved: 2015-05-20
Retrieved: 2015-05-20
Retrieved: 2015-05-20
```

Comment: Looks safe to me, except maybe null handling. Thanks! I'm still wondering how to do it with Oracle DB instead of H2 (which stores a second's precision in a `DATE`). That would be a different question, though.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution also works. I prefer the conversion via `String` in the accepted answer, because it avoids the timezone tinkering shown below. It may however not work the same way on all databases because some, e.g. Oracle, have a different definition of `DATE`.

```
static LocalDate retrieve(DataSource ds) throws SQLException {
  try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
       Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM people limit 1")) {
    if (rs.next()) {
      ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
      TimeZone z = TimeZone.getTimeZone(utc);
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(z);
      java.sql.Date retrieved = rs.getDate("born", cal);
      long time = retrieved.getTime();
      java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(time);
      Instant instant = utilDate.toInstant();
      ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(utc);
      return zdt.toLocalDate();
    }
  }
  throw new IllegalStateException("No data");
}
```

The conversion via `java.util.Date` is outlined in this question, as suggested by user Tunaki: [Missed opportunity to fix JDBC date handling in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548331/missed-opportunity-to-fix-jdbc-date-handling-in-java-8)