# Need find the number of days by taking date differnce in sqlite android

Tags: android, sql

I need to get the no of days by taking the date difference of one date confirmation date hard coded value and other with current date in sqlite.

Comment: [Refer this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/difference-between-2-dates-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (julianday(Date('now')) - julianday(ConfirmationDate)) FROM [TABLE]
```