# Using Timestamp in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp

I have created a database for my application and I use `timestamp` (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) as an attribute of my table. How can I basically query the database to get the last 7 days results? 
I was thinking something like that `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date('now','-7 days')` but it doesnt seem to work since i dont actually compare it with my timestamp.

Comment: May be this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/difference-between-2-dates-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite only has very few [Date and Time Functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). So your best bet would be creating two compatible datetime strings in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (one for today and one for one week ago). Then feed those values to a SQLite query (you can compare with `<` or `>`).