# How do I sort my Django Query Set against today date?

Tags: django

Does anyone know how I can sort (in this instance date) my django query set against todays date ?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
```

My goal is to list the name and date entries. At the top of the list will be the entry with the date that is closest to todays date (day/month).

Comment: What does "to sort against" mean? You can sort by date with ordinary `.order_by('date')`.

Comment: @PavelAnossov I guess he means `[today, 2 days ago, 3 days in future, 4 days ago, ...]` - sort relative to today

Comment: can you provide a sample output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#extra) queryset method to select additional data from database table.

This is example that works with MySql:

```
Person.objects.extra(select={
    'datediff': 'ABS(DATEDIFF(date, NOW()))'}).order_by('datediff')
```

DATEDIFF - returns difference in days bewteen two dates,
ABS - returns absolute value. For sqlite, there is different syntax, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/difference-between-2-dates-in-sqlite).

**EDIT: use current year**

```
Person.objects.extra(select={
    'datediff': "ABS(DATEDIFF(CONCAT(YEAR(now()), '-', MONTH(date), '-', DAY(date)), NOW()))"}
).order_by('datediff')
```

**EDIT 2: optimized ***

```
from datetime import date
dayofyear = int(date.today().strftime("%j"))

datediff = 'LEAST(ABS(DAYOFYEAR(date) - %d), ABS((366 - %d + DAYOFYEAR(date))) MOD 366)' % (
      dayofyear, dayofyear
    )
Person.objects.extra(select={'datediff': datediff}).order_by('datediff')
```

**EDIT 3: closest date after given (todays) date**

```
    from datetime import date
    dayofyear = int(date.today().strftime("%j"))

    datediff = '(DAYOFYEAR(date) - %d + 365) MOD 365' % (
          dayofyear
        )
    Persion.objects.extra(select={'datediff': datediff}).order_by('datediff')
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this would work if I could perform this query but without the year i.e the closest day/month to the current date.

Comment: What do you mean with "but without the year" - do you mean that 04-15-1999 would come before 04-01-2013 (with assumption that current date is 04-15-2013.)

Comment: So if you have 12-4-1980 and 1-4-1991 and the date was 9-4-2013 then 12-4-1980 would come first. i.e I only want to sort the dates using the month and day as each will be used as a date of birthday. So I want to see the closest birthday.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use current year. This could be optimised.

Comment: "Edit 2" version compares days of year and not dates.

Comment: Ive tried the EDIT1 option but I get :
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Thanks it kind of works but now against todays date the 15th April comes before June 6th. Where I want show the next closet date, i.e the next upand coming birthday.

Comment: Do you want to show sort by closest date after given date? solution above sorts by closest date, bot before and after given day/month.

Comment: Yep that's correct, I want to show sort by closest date after given (todays) date, Thanks again.

Comment: Added EDIT 3: closest date after given (todays) date - this should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Many Thanks, just want I was after :o)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sort based on date, you can order as: `.order_by('date')` on a result queryset.

I'm not sure if that answers your question. In case you mean you want to select only the Persons with date of today, you can use:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
persons_with_date_today = Person.objects.filter(date=now)
```

Comment: This is filtering the results, the OP needs to sort it based on today's date

Comment: I know, that's what I also answered - but because of ambiguity in the wording of OP I also added explanation in case he needed filtering.

Comment: The question is, sort in increasing order of difference in timestamp relative to now

Comment: example `[today, 2 days ago, 3 days in future, 4 days ago, ...]`

Comment: Just a note... that is not timezone-aware so even if you have `USE_TZ` set, it won't use it. Django's `django.utils.timezone` has a `now` method that IS timezone aware so depending on your needs, `timezone.now()` may be better.

Comment: Ive looked at all the options and tested but in all cases either the entry was filtered based on todays date or the entries were sorted but date rather then show the most current (against todays date) at the top.