# Sqlite date difference

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to get the Sqlite date difference. I found a way like this

```
sqlite> SELECT julianday('now') - julianday('1776-07-04');
```

But this gives the output like this. `86798.7094695023`. I want to show it as `86798` the number of days only.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try casting your expression to an `Integer` if you only want whole number days:

```
SELECT CAST(JULIANDAY('now') - JULIANDAY('1776-07-04')) As INTEGER
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/difference-between-2-dates-in-sqlite) for more information.