# Using now() for sqlite testing

Tags: mysql, laravel, sqlite

I'm writing tests for my Laravel application and using MySQL for my development database but using SQLite in memory for my testing database with PHPUnit.

I'm trying to write a query that will get the current datetime for my development query and for the testing of my query.

Right now I have the following.

```
->select(DB::raw('DATEDIFF(IFNULL(DATE(champions.lost_on), now()), DATE(champions.won_on)) as length))
```

It says that I can't use now() with SQLite. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: It says I can't use DATEDIFF either with SQLite

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/difference-between-2-dates-in-sqlite) you will need something like:

```
SELECT julianday(champions.won_on) - coalesce(julianday(champions.lost_on), julianday('now'))
```

You might want to cast that to integer.