# Update sql db table columns using another column value

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have this addresses TABLE of my patients and one the column has as integer the number of days since I have last seen the patients.
I need this to be updated using the current date, which is not a problem to get, and another column value from the same TABLE.

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
      c.execute("""UPDATE addresses SET
      days_since_last_appointment = :day""",
      {
      'day': (datetime.now()-       last_appointment_day)
       })
```

I'm using Python 3.9 and sqlite3

Any idea?

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: ValueError: time data '.!entry4' does not match format '%d%m%Y

Comment: I think the main issue is to access another column string value while updating one column

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to a table column as if it were a Python variable.

You can do the arithmetic in the SQL query itself:

```
c.execute("""UPDATE addresses
SET days_since_last_appointment = julianday('now') - julianday(last_appointment_day)""")
```

See [Difference between 2 dates in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/difference-between-2-dates-in-sqlite/34383293)

Comment: Thank you, this seems that it's gonna be working, I'm now getting a database is locked error, just saw online that I neeeded to increase the timeout but no idea how do that. Where to put that OPTIONS thing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151026/how-do-i-unlock-a-sqlite-database

Comment: well mate. Thanks a lot! Have a nice day