# Pandasql date difference

Tags: python, pandasql

I'm trying to get the difference between two dates in Pandasql (using a dataframe as table),
But it doesn't work.

[image: Code image]

the code:
query3 = '''
SELECT
user_id
, transaction_id
, amount_in_eur
, min(timestamp)
, onboarding_completed_at
, (min(timestamp)-onboarding_completed_at)
FROM new_df
WHERE event_kind = 'crypto_withdrawal'
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING amount_in_eur >= 2000
AND (min(timestamp)-onboarding_completed_at) < 4;

'''

mysql(query3)

I'm using a pandas dataframe!

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please include your code as text, not as an image. An image is impossible to debug. [ask]

Comment: Are you using pandas or an db engine to get the difference ? If the latter, include the db you're using

Comment: @LucasAbreu [pandasql](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/#querying), the package the asker is using, uses SQLite to run the queries.

Comment: Thanks, @Nick ODell.  This link should help the asker then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/difference-between-2-dates-in-sqlite/14790580.   Seems some specifics from SQLite date calculation