# how to get average of two date fields

Tags: django

I want to subtract the time user's result object is created and the time user has registered.
these are my models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=13)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, default=None)

class Results(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    score = models.FloatField()
```

in my views, I want something like this: (Sum of all Results.created dates - Sum of all User.created_at dates)/ len(all users). how can I achieve this?

I userd the aggregate to write this line of code for testing:

```
Results.objects.filter(user__is_staff=False, user__role='applicant').aggregate(Avg(F('created')))
```

but it gives me this error:

```
You cannot use Sum, Avg, StdDev, and Variance aggregations on date/time fields in sqlite3 since date/time is saved as text.
```

Comment: You should use `aggregate()` method ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/))

Comment: I edited my question. I used this aggregate but it gives me an error see the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're computing the average *difference* between user account creation date and the date each of their quizzes is completed. Imagine we have three Results:

1. User A completes the quiz 3 days after creating their account.
2. User A completes a second quiz 4 days after creating their account.
3. User B completes a quiz 5 days after creating their account.

The computation would be the average of 3, 4, and 5.

You can accomplish this with [Django's query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/).

1. For better accuracy, change your `created` field in `Results` to a `DateTimeField` instead of a `DateField`. Otherwise, your calculations won't account for partial days.
2. Use the `F` function to refer to your desired fields: `F('created')` refers to a `Result`'s creation date, and `F('user__created_at')` refers to the `Result`'s corresponding `User`'s account creation date.
3. Use `Func` to create a `JulianDay` class, which represents SQLite's JulianDay function. This function lets you [find the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/difference-between-2-dates-in-sqlite).
4. Compute an `Avg` aggregation, using a `FloatField()` as the output field's data type. (Note: You can remove the `output_field=FloatField()` part once you change your `created` field in `Results` to a `DateTimeField`.)

```python
# Import your models
from question70860461.models import User, Quiz, Results

# Import Django query expressions
from django.db.models import F, Func, FloatField, Avg

# Set up some example objects
u = User(username='jeffb', first_name='Jeff', last_name='Booth')
u.save()

q = Quiz()
q.save()

r = Results(quiz=q, user=u, score=100)
r.save()

r2 = Results(quiz=q, user=u, score=200)
r2.save()

# The usual trick to find the days between two dates on SQLite
# is to use the JulianDay function. Create a Django Func wrapper
# for this function:
class JulianDay(Func):
    function='JulianDay'

# Run a query that finds the average
# time between User creation and Results creation.
x = Results.objects.aggregate(
      result=Avg(JulianDay(F('created')) - JulianDay(F('user__created_at')),
             output_field=FloatField()))
```

Comment: I did all this but it still gives me this error: class JulianDay(Func):
    function='JulianDay'

Comment: @Sam Could you please paste the full error message into your comment? This worked for me in my Python manage.py shell.